# TEXTJOIN of INDEX MATCH unique values if value on another table is contained in a cell in the same row

Tags: indexing, excel-formula, textjoin, excel-tables

On Column B I'm trying to get a TEXTJOIN with delimiter "," of INDEX MATCH to the price range you see on Table B. Because cell A5 contains "Apple" then "$$$" is one of the values I need, also A6 contains "Banana" then "$$" is the second value i need. Finally cell A7 contains "Pineapple" but because "$$$" is already was selected because of apple then no need to add it again.

[image]

Comment: just replace the FILERXML part from your last question with the range: `=TEXTJOIN(",", 1, UNIQUE( XLOOKUP( [Fruits],TableB[Fruit], TableB[Price Range],"",0)))`

Comment: Works. Thank you! good eyes on noticing my previous question as well